# jQuery: Trouble getting hide() and show() to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm practicing with it. I have created two tables which show the pronunciation of the military nato alphabet and phonetic alphabet. Upon selecting "Alfabet" or "Cijfers" in the dropdown box, the corresponding table must be shown. This is not working, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help me pinpoint the issue here.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGUHy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cijfers").hide();
});

$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    if ($('#dropdown option:selected').text() == "Alfabet"){
        $('.cijfers').hide();
        $('.alfabet').show();
    } else if ($('#dropdown option:selected').text() == "Cijfers"){
        $('.alfabet').hide();
        $('.cijfers').show();
    } else {
        $('.cijfers').hide();
    } });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't bind to your select because your `"#dropdown"` selector looks for an element by id but you gave your element a name. You could select by name (using `"[name=dropdown]"`) but the best here is to use an id.

Change

```
    <select name="dropdown">
```

to

```
    <select id="dropdown">
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMyuA/)

Comment: Ok weird that I didn't noticed that one :) It works in the jsFiddle now, but whatever I do, it doesn't work locally in the xampp server. I have copied everything over from the jsfiddle and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: it may sound silly, but I encourage you to copy all this code in a local html file and try to run it. I tell you, this code is exactly as in the jsFiddle, but it just won't work!

Comment: 1) check you import jQuery 2) check you have no error in the console 3) put the binding in the ready callback as in http://jsfiddle.net/YtrDE/

Comment: Putting this function in the ready callback did the trick :) Thank you so much dystroy! I will mark your answer as accepted.